# Keras sequence classification in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, machine-learning, nlp

I am trying to perform sequence classification using keras in python 3. I am trying to classify sequences of words. In my data, I used word_2_vec to transform the words to a array of shape 300. My training data is as follows

X --> List of list of word vectors (all list of word vectors are 50 word vectors in length)
Y --> List of correct classes that are one hot encoded (like this: [[0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0]...])

When I try to initialize the model and fit my data to it, I keep getting errors. I am new to deep learning using keras. What should the layers of my model be. Also one particular error I am getting is that my input_shape is incorrect. What is my input_shape in this case?

Code:

```
    training_data = []
    with open(INTENT_RECOGNITION_TRAINING, 'r') as json_file:
        json_obj = json.load(json_file)
        for data in json_obj['data']:
            for query in data['queries']:
                words = [START_TOKEN] + word_tokenize(query[0]) + [END_TOKEN]
                if len(words) > JText.MAX_QUERY_LENGTH:
                    JText.MAX_QUERY_LENGTH = len(words)
                training_data.append((words, data['intent']))
    training_data = [(JText._pad_sequence(ws, JText.MAX_QUERY_LENGTH), intent) for (ws, intent) in training_data]
    for i in range(len(training_data)):
        if training_data[i][1] not in JText.INTENTS:
            JText.INTENTS.append(training_data[i][1])
        query_vector = []
        for w in training_data[i][0]:
            if w in JText.WORD2VEC.vocab:
                query_vector.append(JText.WORD2VEC[w])
            else:
                query_vector.append(np.zeros(300))
        training_data[i] = (query_vector, training_data[i][1])
    random.shuffle(training_data)
    X_train = [tup[0] for tup in training_data]
    y_train = [tup[1] for tup in training_data]
    y_labelencoder = LabelEncoder()
    y_train = y_labelencoder.fit_transform(y_train).reshape(-1, 1)
    y_onehotencoder = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features=[0])
    y_train = y_onehotencoder.fit_transform(y_train).toarray()
    recognizer = Sequential([
        LSTM(100, input_shape=(JText.MAX_QUERY_LENGTH, 300)),
        Dense(len(JText.INTENTS), activation='sigmoid')
    ])
    recognizer.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
    recognizer.fit(X_train, y_train, nb_epoch=100, batch_size=10)
```

Getting this error:

```
Exception: Error when checking model input: expected lstm_input_1 to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (21, 1)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without the keras model code or the error message it is very difficult to provide an exact answer.
I will try to help by stating a general solution as per the available info.

1. I am assuming that you are using LSTM in Keras to do the sequence classification. If that is the case, your input should be a 3D ndarray of dimensions (batch_size,Time_steps,length_each_word_vector). So in your case the input is a ndarray of shape (no_of_sequences_to_train,50,300) assuming that there are 50 words in each sequence.
2. About what layers you should use, since the y argument provided seems like there are only 3 classification classes. If that is the case you may consider adding a Dense layer with output_dim = 3 (that is first argument 3)

This [blog](http://machinelearningmastery.com/sequence-classification-lstm-recurrent-neural-networks-python-keras/) is a good example of sequence classification, should provide some intuitive ideas to a beginner.

Hope this helps

**UPDATE**
I am trying to do something similar and had encountered the same problem.
Form your code it seems that you are passing a list of ndarrays of shape (seq_len, 300). The Keras expects a 3D numpy array not a list of numpy array.

This is how I would reconfigured my training data

```
X_train = np.zeros((len(training_data,MAX_QUERY_LENGTH,300))
for i in range(len(training_data)):
     tup = training_data[i]
     X_train[i,:,:]=tup[0]
```

The code above is not optimized but it best conveys the changes needed so as to get the LSTM layer accept your input

Hope this Helps

Comment: When I set the input shape of (len, 300) I get this error message `Exception: Error when checking model input: expected lstm_input_1 to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (21, 1)` I have updated the question with my code @SebinjudeShaolin